# Change div opacity with scroll

Tags: scroll, opacity, parallax

I'm trying to build a parallax based website and I wanted to know how can I change the opacity of a div (with a quote inside) as we scroll down the page. I know that some related questions have been answered here but since I'm a complete newbie in terms of JS and JQ i wasn't able to completely understand most of those answers.

Comment: Your question is too broad to get a useful answer. Please update your question to show what you have already tried so far and what is or isn't working for you.

Comment: I actually haven't tried anything because i'm clueless...  I just have this Div "<div class="4frase" data-type="sprite" data-offsetY="1250" data-Xposition="45%" data-speed="8"><img src="img/frase4.png" class="frase4" width="800px"></div>" with a image inside it and i wanted it to change it's opacity when i'm scrolling down...